# Python Pandas manipulate df and create excel with styles and links

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

**Q.1: GROUP SIMILAR ROWS**

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
       TTL1    TTL2    TTL3
0      val1    val2    val3
1      val1    val2    val3
2      val1    val2    val3
3      val1    val2    val3
134    val1    val2    val3
135    val1    val2    val3
136    val1    val2    val3
205    val1    val2    val3
```

I want to check if the index numbers are succeeding (eg. 1,2,3 or 56,57,58 etc.) and if so, add another column to show that they are in the same group, so the output should be:

```
       TTL1    TTL2    TTL3   GROUP_TTL
0      val1    val2    val3      0
1      val1    val2    val3      0
2      val1    val2    val3      0
3      val1    val2    val3      0
134    val1    val2    val3      1
135    val1    val2    val3      1
136    val1    val2    val3      1
205    val1    val2    val3      2
```

**Q.2: MANIPULATE THE EXCEL FILE:**

Now for the part that I'm not sure can be done in pandas and python:

I want to color the rows in the excel, so each group of rows would be in the same color. so group 0 would be green, 1 yellow etc.

and I also want to add links inside the excel sheet, to some other excel sheets on the computer.

Is it possible with pandas and python?

thank you!

Comment: I think it's a little bit too much for one question... Can you split it into three or two questions?

Comment: @MaxU like so? look at my edit

Comment: actually i meant new separate questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use first convert [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html) `index` for function [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) (is not implemented for `index` yet) and then compare if values are not `1`. Get `boolean Series` which can cumulative sum by [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and last substract `1`:

```
df['GROUP_TTL'] = (df.index.to_series().diff() != 1).cumsum().sub(1)

print (df)
     TTL1  TTL2  TTL3  GROUP_TTL
0    val1  val2  val3          0
1    val1  val2  val3          0
2    val1  val2  val3          0
3    val1  val2  val3          0
134  val1  val2  val3          1
135  val1  val2  val3          1
136  val1  val2  val3          1
205  val1  val2  val3          2
```

Coloring:

```
#http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_conditional.html
len_index = len(df.index) + 1
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=None)
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
worksheet.conditional_format('D2:D'+str(len_index), {'type': '3_color_scale'})
writer.save()
```

Comment: works perfect. thank you. can you explain it a bit? and is there a way to do the second part of the question?

Comment: second q is more complicated for me, please give me a time.

Comment: waht do you think add links?

Comment: for example: I built my new dataframe from several excel sheets that I cutted and combined, so I want to add to each row, a link to the original worksheet that I extracted it from. so for example add another column `ORIGINAL_SHEET` and a link to the sheet and row number.

Comment: I looking for links and I only find [this](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_hyperlink.html). If it is possible it is very complicated, maybe author of `xlsxwriter` (`John McNamara`) answer it.

Comment: But I think you need separately ask question with your problem, add some code (e.g. from link) for [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ok, thank you for your help! I will try to learn for it now. @jezrael one other small question: is it possible to add a blank row after each `group`? so it will be more visual the seperation of the groups.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133002/discussion-between-thedajon-and-jezrael).

Comment: I added some examples for the link part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

> I also want to add links inside the excel sheet, to some other excel sheets on the computer.

That is possible, see the [`write_url()`](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-write-url) section of the docs. For example:

```
# Link to a cell on the current worksheet.
worksheet.write_url('A1',  'internal:Sheet1!A1')

# Link to a cell on another worksheet.
worksheet.write_url('A2',  'internal:Sheet2!A1')

# Link to another Excel workbook.
worksheet.write_url('A3', r'external:c:\temp\foo.xlsx')

# Link to a worksheet cell in another workbook.
worksheet.write_url('A4', r'external:c:\foo.xlsx#Sheet2!A1')

# Link to a worksheet another workbook with a relative link.
worksheet.write_url('A5', r'external:..\foo.xlsx')

# Link to a worksheet another workbook with a network link.
worksheet.write_url('A6', r'external:\\NET\share\foo.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thank you for this samples. What do you think, is possible add at least one to official docs sample? I think [here](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_hyperlink.html)

Comment: I'll update the `write_url()` docs to add explanations of the different options, like above. As for an example program, I could do that. I did one the Perl version of the library ([here](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX/Examples.pm#Example:_hyperlink2.pl)) but the dir layout is specific to Windows and the example itself is a little busy so I didn't replicate it in Python, Lua or C but I'll look at it again. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: well, it's even easier than we thought. I don't have to use `write_url()`, I can also just do something like this: `df['col_name'] = r'external:XL_LINK'` and it works! is there also a way to make field in a *bold* text? like the columns headers or the index column that is bold?

Comment: When working with Pandas/XlsxWriter you can only format rows and columns and not individual cells, see the [Formatting of the Dataframe output](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#formatting-of-the-dataframe-output) section of the docs. If you need more precise XlsxWriter formatting then it is probably best to extract the data from the dataframe and write it using the XlsxWriter APIs.

Comment: so how can I make all the row as bold? choose only a specific row and make it bold?