# Using pandas to create links between spreadsheets

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I'm working on a small project and in it I have to link cells from other spreadsheets (T1, T2, T3...) in a spreadsheet (we can call it consolidated). They all have the same size and shape.

Follow the instructions available here:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30110511/create-a-hyperlink-to-a-different-excel-sheet-in-the-same-workbook)
but without success

```python
with pd.ExcelWriter('Consolidado.xlsx', mode='a', engine='openpyxl', if_sheet_exists='replace') as write:         
    wb = write.book
    ws = wb['Plan1']
    ws['A1'].hyperlink = "T1.xlsx#Sheet1!A1"
```

Basically I have to do the following:
In the consolidated worksheet `cell.Sheet[A1]` I have to leave an active link to `T1.Sheet[A1]`.

In Excel it would be `='path[T1.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1`

When using the code above, the following result appears

```
"T1.xlsx#Sheet1!A1"
```

and when I click, I am directed to another spreadsheet.
But the value that is in this other spreadsheet should appear to be added to the formulas below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas manipulate df and create excel with styles and links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41611887/python-pandas-manipulate-df-and-create-excel-with-styles-and-links)

Comment: *"But the value that is in this other spreadsheet should appear to be added to the formulas below."* -- what formulas below? Do you mean the hyperlink cell's value should be the value from the `T1.xlsx->Sheet1->A1` cell?

Comment: Links to external workbooks have to be handled using external links.

Comment: Exactly Johnny Henly. For example, in cell A1 there should be the number from the other worksheet which would be 1, in cell A2 it would have the value of 5. Cell A3 would be a sum (A1:A2).

Comment: As CC states, these links are external links not hyperlinks so to add to a cell you want to use `ws['A1'].value = "='C:\Temp\Links\[T1.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1"` . Obviously using whatever path your workbook is in.